# How to load CakeDC.Comments plugin on CakeDC.Ratings plugin?

Tags: php, cakephp, comments, rating-system, cakedc

I am using CakeDC's ratings plugin in my application to enable users rate on any model entry, such as a company in companies table.

I also want to allow users to comment on that rating. Ratings plugin creates an entry in ratings table for each rating. So what I want is, each rating entry should be commented by the user when he/she is rating on it. Without touching the plugin core, how can I achieve this?

Note: I am using Cakephp 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

The nature of the comment plugin is to allow multiple comments. So not only would the user be able to comment, anyone else could comment on the rating and the other comments. If this is not what you want, I would suggest doing something a little more custom where you add an extra column to the ratings table. In the form, you add the comment box Rating.comment so it is a one-to-one ratio comment to rating. Then when the rating is saved, it will save the comment with the rating.

Comment: maybe yes. but after I asked this question, I noticed that, when a user updates his/her previous rating, rating plugin deletes the old rating row from ratings table and creates a new record. this is also another challenge to face. but in any case there's an easy workaround for that.